# $meteor.object reset function changes not reflected in user interface

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I started with this: https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially/releases/tag/step_06.

There is a Parties collection where each party has name and description properties, and I have added a **things** array. Data is initialized like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if (Parties.find().count() === 0) {
            var parties = [
                {
                    'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone',
                    'description': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
                    'things': [{'thing': 'Thing 1'},{'thing': 'Thing 2'}]
                },
                {
                    'name': 'All dubstep all the time',
                    'description': 'Get it on!',
                    'things': [{'thing': 'Thing 1'},{'thing': 'Thing 2'}]
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Savage lounging',
                    'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.',
                    'things': [{'thing': 'Thing 1'},{'thing': 'Thing 2'}]
                }
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < parties.length; i++)
                Parties.insert(parties[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the controller definition:

```
    angular.module("socially").controller("PartyDetailsCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$meteor',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $meteor) {
        $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);
        $scope.aThing = $scope.getReactively('party.things[0]');
        $scope.favoriteThingIndex = 1;

        $scope.save = function () {
            $scope.party.save().then(function (numberOfDocs) {
                console.log('save success doc affected ', numberOfDocs);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('save error', error);
            });
        };

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.party.reset();
        };
    }]);
```

The view (party-details.ng.html) looks like this:

```
Here you will see and change the details of the party:

<input ng-model="party.name">
<input ng-model="party.description">
<input ng-model="aThing.thing">
<input ng-model="party.things[favoriteThingIndex].thing">

<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>

<button ng-click="reset()">Reset form</button>
<button ui-sref="parties">Cancel</button>
```

I can alter any of the 4 inputs and click the **Save** button and the changes will get saved successfully, but if I alter all 4 inputs and click the **Reset form** button then each input will revert back to its original text except the third (with ng-model="aThing.thing").

Can somebody explain why the third input text does not get reset?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.getReactively` needs to be wrapped in [`$meteor.autorun`](http://angular-meteor.com/api/getReactively):

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $meteor) {
    $meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
        $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId, false);
        $scope.aThing = $scope.getReactively('party.things[0]');
        $scope.favoriteThingIndex = 1;

        $scope.save = function () {
            $scope.party.save().then(function (numberOfDocs) {
                console.log('save success doc affected ', numberOfDocs);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('save error', error);
            });
        };

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.party.reset();
        };
    });

}]);
```